# Why my tableView always work with empty cell?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I made a simple code for tableView to display some player data; however, I got the empty table all the time.

This is a table with data fetched from the site.
I want to show the table with player number(as section) and player name(as row).

But after I run the program, it comes out the empty cells and seems no fetching attempt.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks a lot.

```
#import "playerName.h"

@interface playerName ()
@end

@implementation playerName
@synthesize players = _players;
@synthesize sectionInRtf = _sectionInRtf;

- (NSMutableDictionary *)getPlayerFormRtf
{
    if (!_players) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file_on_site"];
        _players = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];
    }
    return _players;
}
- (NSArray *)getSections
{
    if (!_sectionInRtf) {
        _sectionInRtf = [self.players allKeys];
    }
    return _sectionInRtf;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Players";
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.sectionInRtf.count;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *namesInSection = [self.players objectForKey:[self.sectionInRtf objectAtIndex:section]];
    return namesInSection.count;
}
//Additional Method
- (NSString *)name:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *nameInSection2 = [self.players objectForKey:[self.sectionInRtf objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    return [nameInSection2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"players";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self name:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}

@end
```

Comment: did you set your viewController class as a datasource for the tableView?

Comment: No.. I don't know how to link them.
I just use the storyboard to create a TableViewController and link the  custom class(playerName) what I create.

Comment: I use Xcode4 1.I create the Single View project. 2.delet the ViewController in storyboard. 3.drag TableViewController into storyboard and link the custom class that I create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you are trying to override the accessor methods but you are not using the correct naming. I make this assumption since you never actually call `getPlayerFormRtf`.

The code should work (though not well) with two simple modifications.

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)players
{
    if (!_players) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file_on_site"];
        _players = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];
    }
    return _players;
}
- (NSArray *)sectionInRtf
{
    if (!_sectionInRtf) {
        _sectionInRtf = [self.players allKeys];
    }
    return _sectionInRtf;
}
```

**PLEASE** note that this is an *extremely* bad idea, referring to the synchronous loading of a url, since your placeholder url string seems to imply a network access url. This risks blocking the main thread long enough for the application to be killed.

Comment: Oh my God..
Seems like that I lost the basic knowledge..
Thank you so much for your help!
I'll really think of your note.

Comment: No Problem. And don't worry about it we all get a bit myopic at times.